# How to make find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep "text" to work with filename with spaces

Tags: linux, windows, shell

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep "text"
```

fail when file name has spaces

How to make this to work with filename with spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "text"
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work for all file names and it will also be slightly more efficient because it avoids the need for a pipeline:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec grep "text" {} +
```